# What is $p(x)dx$

Tags: calculus, probability, derivatives, probability-distributions

I was playing with an equation using what I think it is called "infinitesimal calculus" and I arrived at this equation form:

$$
f(t) = g(x)p_t(x)dx
$$

where $f(t)$ and $p_t(x)$ are both probability density functions.

I don't know how to deal with it or how to get rid of it rather.

I thought

$$
p_t(x)dx = P_t(x + dx) - P_t(x) 
$$

where $P_t(x)$ is the cumulative function. This gives me the wrong answer.

Any advice?

**Edit**

So based on some really good comments - I checked my math and I realized that

$$f(t) \neq h(t)dt$$

Comment: If $p(x)$ is the probability density function of a random variable $X$ then informally $p(x)\mathrm{d}x\approx \mathbb{P}(X\in (x,x+dx))$. You will have to explain more about the context of this question, what this “wrong answer” is and how it came to be.

Comment: @LoveTooNap29 so my assumption above was correct? I don't understand your notation but it seems similar

Comment: Yea but algebraic manipulations of such informal relations are prone to errors. You should just use (in your notation now but omitting the time $t$ subscript) the definition of the distribution as the integral of the density: $P(x)=\int_{-\infty}^x p(u) \mathrm{d}u$ (for continuous RVs)

Comment: Is there a $dt$ missing on the left-hand side of your first equation, or an $\int$ on the right?

Comment: @J.G. There was... $h(t)dt=f(t)$

Comment: @EdvBeq You shouldn't abbreviate $h(t)dt$ ad $f(t)$, especially if your post doesn't even mention $h$.For starters, it suppresses the $dt$ dependence; it also obscures the fact that $hdt$ is infinitesimal. But no matter: $h(t)dt=g(x)p_t(x)dx$ is consistent with a chain rule, viz. $h(t)=g(x)p_t(x)\dot{x}(t)$.

Comment: @J.G.  I’m sorry - I thought mentioning that they were probability densities was sufficient but thank you